# Getting NaN as output in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I am getting `nan` output while using pandas DataFrames. Why I am getting this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Using the `index` kwarg when your data already has indexes will reindex the existing data based on the `index` values. Which will cause `nan` in this case because the default indexes of the Series will not align with the new indexes specified. You can either remove the indexes from the `Series`, or do `df = pd.DataFrame(pd_dict)` then `df.index = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']` after